# visualising l*a*b space values in matlab or any software

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have table of l,a,b values and want to visualise these colors in matlab (or any other suitable software). Is there any quick way like series of rectangles filled with color values from the table?

Answer (score 2):

There are several versions of the [Lab color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space), but presumably you're referring to most common, [CIELAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space#CIELAB). You can use [`imwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) in Matlab to create a TIFF image with `'cielab'` specified for the [`'Colorspace'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html#input_argument_namevalue_colorspace) option. I [wouldn't trust Matlab as a viewer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/39837) for the resultant images though. Photoshop in lab mode (from the menu bar: Image > Mode > Lab Color) would be a good choice if you want work with and see the closest thing to the actual CIELAB space. Other viewers/editors may convert to RGB or CMYK before rendering to the screen (likely without warning you), but maybe you don't mind. If you just want to convert from CIELAB to RGB, you might find [these functions](http://robotics.stanford.edu/~ruzon/software/rgblab.html) useful.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes I meant CIELAB I tried to use photoshop instead. But had the problem since my values are having two decimal points.Searched further where I found a photoshop plug-in which allowed me to enter upto two decimal points. Here is the plugin file for photoshop:[link]https://sites.google.com/site/cliffpicsmisc/home/plugins/LabWriter.8bf?attredirects=0&d=1   but I had to manually place the value from my table which was tedious but I am done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research, I found out there is a plugin called 'color inspector' that can be used along with ImageJ (all opensource tools). Have excellent capacity to view and analyse different color space. Even it has some color tools that matlab yet to have. here is imageJ: http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/download.html
and the plugin
http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/plugins/color-inspector.html

Hope this is useful to someone